# Where can I purchase good and inexpensive protein powder in Hong Kong?

Tags: health, shopping, hong-kong

I'm looking for some good protein powders with good protein/total-weight ratio, something they might be making/selling from USA. Are there any stores that sell the genuine stuff for less than double or triple the price I'd pay if I were in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what price you're used to paying in the US, but there are many shops called BC Fitness and Wellness. Here is a link to their website that has the list off all their stores, locations and opening hours. It also has a list of all their products and anything else you need to know about them.

http://www.bcshop.hk/en/our-shops.html

Quoted from the 'About Us' section of the website, it also says, **"Our products are imported directly from the USA, Canada and Europe on a regular basis, including multiple brands, and always ensuring the freshest products available"**. Which also answers the question of being made/sold/imported from the USA.